# Java read out a serial port

Tags: java, serial-port

I would like to read out informations from a serial interface with Java 8.
I'd use SDS011 sensor and I'd like the sensor-output in a command line.
I took a script, but it hasn't have a function to bring the data to a gui (or command line).
This is my script:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class sds011auslesen implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;

    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
    };

    private BufferedReader input;
    private static OutputStream output;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),TIME_OUT);

            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    public void Serial(String ncom){
        if(Integer.parseInt(ncom)>=3 && Integer.parseInt(ncom)<=9)
            PORT_NAMES[2] = "COM" + ncom;
        initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Serial Comms Started");
    }

    public synchronized void send(int b){
        try{
            output.write(b);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public synchronized int read(){
        int b = 0;

        try{
            b = (int)input.read();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your current code do?  Do you get any error message or does it just appear to hang?

Comment: I have problems with gnu.io, i cannot add my serial port (devTTYUSB0...). If I run this script it opens a window where i can add my serial port, but thats not the big problem. Error Messages arent yet. But I like to have a script which has an output from my sensor data. This script hasn't a data output.